# How to Find and Replace word from URL in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have come through many relevant questions but my scenario is different. . . . . . . . .  . . . . . 
I have this URL Address:

```
http://www.domain.com/word-one/word-two/word-three/word-four
```

there are 4 words after slash in my URL, and i want find 'word-three' replace it with anything.
How can i do it with Jquery on Click event.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

> (Edited)

There is something i forgot to mention that is word-three is not hard coded maybe something else at this place. So the thing is We have to change the word after 3 Slashes.

Comment: I think the methods `.split('/')` and `.join('/')` might help you

Comment: If you break your problem down into separate steps (step 1: parse URL for certain level dir), you will find your situation is not a unique snowflake. Please try again with your searching.

Comment: Where is this URL, the `document.location`, in an `img` element's `src` an `a` element's `href`? What are you, or your users, clicking to trigger this change? Why is this scenario 'different'? What have you tried from the many, *many* similar questions that didn't work? Where did they go wrong?

Comment: Dear David, If you dont understand my question then there is no need to hyper. just ask me. And if you found any scenario that is similar with this one. Then Talk

Comment: I did ask, you neglected to respond to the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace 'word-three' with 'edited'

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/word-one/word-two/word-three/word-four";
url.replace(url.split('/')[5], 'edited');
```

Comment: This is a fine solution Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/word-one/word-two/word-three/word-four"

var array = url.split("/");
console.log(array);
array[5] = "someOtherWord";
var new_url = array.join("/")
console.log(new_url)
```

console.log for debugging purposes.

[View on Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ5bJ/)

Edit:

I'm assuming here you know how to wrap this into onclick event.  Also, you will need to pass your url somehow to the event handler.  There is more than one way of doing that depending on your code, and where the url comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery..

1.Use `.replace` (but it only replaces the first occurrence, not all occurrences)

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/word-one/word-two/word-three/word-four";
url.replace('word-three','somex');
```

`//result "http://www.domain.com/word-one/word-two/somex/word-four"`

2.For replacing multiple occurrences, use `split` & `join`

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/word-one/word-two/word-three/word-four";
url.split('word').join('somex');

//result "http://www.domain.com/somex-one/somex-two/somex-three/somex-four"
```